# io.connect not working on local html page

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, socket.io

I have an html page that needs to connect to a node.js server via socket.

The code works when in an html page that's hosted on my EC2 however, it's not working when I have it on an HTML page on my machine. Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript src="http://54.213.92.113:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var socket = io.connect('http://54.213.92.113:8080');

    $(document).ready(function(){

        socket.on('jqplot', function(sentdata){
            alert(sentdata);
        });

    });
</script>
```

I have no idea why this isn't working...I feel like i've don't everything correctly!

The javascript works when I comment out the line `var socket = io.connect('http://54.213.92.113:8080');`

Comment: Well, `54.213.92.113:8080` seems to be unreachable. You've also missed a few `"` on some of the `type` attributes. And, what browsers are you using? [Do they support WebSockets](http://caniuse.com/#feat=websockets)?

Comment: Do you know if `socket.io` is falling back to `long-polling` or something of the sort? There are potential issues with cross domain requests.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski sorry about that...the server was not on. I added the missing quotations and it works now!! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Is 54.213.92.113 external EC2 address?

Is 8080 port of instance(security group) opened?

1. ping - use external or ElasticIP
2. nmap(I check, it inaccessible) - add 8080 to instance assigned security group

Comment: Not at the moment, I have it off. I have figured out this problem though. It was a missing quotation mark.